# Pass array in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have this nested array which I am trying to sum the number in the last arrays individually

so it should return 400 for each array also trying to get the average of the total,
for example if it is 400 then it is 100%, if 399 it will be 99.99%, the average needs to be from 100% and dynamic if that makes sense.

I been using javascript map method, but every time I map over the array it returns the same array level, I couldn't access the last array.

arr.map(item => item.map(item2 => item2))

example in code:

```
const arr = [
  [
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 98, 100], // sum 398 -> average 99.99%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
  ],
  [
    [100, 100, 100, 99], // sum 399 -> average 99.99%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
  ]
];
```

the result should be something like this

```
 const arr = [
      [
        {total: 400, average: 100%},
        {total: 400, average: 100%},
        {total: 398, average: 99,99%}, 
        {total: 400, average: 100%},
      ],
      [
        {total: 399, average: 99,99%}, 
        {total: 400, average: 100%},
        {total: 400, average: 100%},
        {total: 400, average: 100%},   
      ]
    ];
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Have a look at [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I been using javascript map method, but every time I map over the array it returns the same array level, I couldn't access the last array

Comment: Then add your attempt, and we should be able to find the problem. Asking us to write a working script for you is off-topic -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (+ [mcve])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would've done something like this

```
  let data = arr.map(section => section.map(row => {
      let tot = row.reduce((pv,cv) => pv+cv,0);
      return {'total':tot,'avg':tot/row.length+"%"}
    }))
```

Comment: I love this solution and it is easy to understand, but what about if the array has 500 or 600? then (tot/400) * 100 won't work, how to make the percentage work dynamically with any array length ?

Comment: @Rio updated it so it would work with any length

Comment: You're awesome, the best answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 98, 100], // sum 398 -> average 99.99%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
  ],
  [
    [100, 100, 100, 99], // sum 399 -> average 99.99%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
    [100, 100, 100, 100], // sum 400 -> average 100%
  ]
];

const result = arr.map((arrOfLists) => arrOfLists.map(list =>
  list.reduce((acc, num, index) => {
   const newTotal=(acc.total||0) + parseInt(num)
    return {
      average: newTotal / list.length,
      total: newTotal
    };
  }, { })))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this method.

```js
  const sumAndAvr = []
  
  arr.forEach((el) => {
      const subsumAndAvr = [];
      el.forEach(ele=>{
          let sum = 0;
    let avg=0;
    ele.map((el2) => {
        sum += el2
       
    })
    avg=sum/ele.length
    subsumAndAvr.push({ total: sum, average: avg + "%" });
})
sumAndAvr.push(subsumAndAvr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to separate the calculations into reusable functions.  Doing so also makes the main function much more simple and readable.  It might look like this:

```js
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
const mean = (ns) => sum (ns) / (ns .length || 1)

const calc = (arr) => arr .map ((xs) => xs .map ((ys) => ({
  total: sum (ys),
  average: mean (ys) + '%'
})))

const arr = [[[100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 100, 98, 100], [100, 100, 100, 100]], [[100, 100, 100, 99], [100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 100, 100, 100]]]

console .log (calc (arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

There's nothing tricky here.  In `mean` we divide by `ns .length || 1` rather than just by `ns .length` to avoid division by zero.

There is a slight inefficiency in calculating the sum of every group twice, once for the sum and one for the mean.  If this is a demonstrated problem in your application, you can of course combine them as done in the answer from Breezer.  But I wouldn't worry much about it unless I tested and found this was an actual hot spot in my code.